# Expand Content Editor children item not showing

Tags: content-editor

In Content Editor, while I expanding the Sitecore content tree of any item children item is not showing. I have enabled the "**Content tree** option in **View** ribbon. But its failed to showing the children item inducing **content, media library, layout, system**

[image]

Comment: Is it a new Sitecore vanilla instance?

Comment: Is there any error details in the log?

Comment: Suggest you check items are present in database via /sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx - then rebuild sitecore_master_index (via control panel -indexing manager)

Comment: @DeanOBrien i have checked the /sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx items presented.

Comment: did you try rebuilding the index?

Comment: Yes, I have done all the index, but it is not showing.

Comment: Now working, right Click specific item =>click refresh. Then child item is showing

Comment: Had you rebuilt the index prior to refreshing? Guessing the tree output could have been cached?

Comment: Yes, I did the indexing. I have cleared the browser cache and Sitecore cache, but that is not effective.